# How to pass user context to QueryRedirector when soft deleting?

Tags: java, eclipselink, audit, soft-delete

We use softdelete and auditing at our Java EE application.
At our tables we have two audit columns indicating remove: *_AUDIT_RD --- timestamp of remove and *_AUDIT_RU --- where we register user, who removed the row.

So our DAO remove method looks like:

```
public void removeItem(ProcessContext callContext, TYPE pItemData) throws ApplicationException {
    pItemData.setAuditRD(DateTimeUtil.getCurrentDate());
    pItemData.setAuditRU(callContext.getUserId());
    super.modifyItem(callContext, pItemData);
}
```

But this does not handle our related-embedded collections (only main entity).

We're trying to implement DeleteRedirector, but we have no idea, how to get UserId here??

```
public class RemoveRedirector implements QueryRedirector {
    public Object invokeQuery(DatabaseQuery query, Record arguments, Session session) {
        ClassDescriptor descriptor = session.getDescriptor(query.getReferenceClass());
        DeleteObjectQuery deleteObjectQuery = (DeleteObjectQuery) query;    
        AbstractItem entityItem = (AbstractItem) deleteObjectQuery.getObject();
        entityItem.setAuditRD(DateTimeUtil.getCurrentDate());   
        //how to get audit user??
        entityItem.setAuditRU(auditUser);
        UpdateObjectQuery updateObjectQuery = new UpdateObjectQuery(entityItem);
        updateObjectQuery.setDescriptor(descriptor);
        deleteObjectQuery.setDescriptor(updateObjectQuery.getDescriptor());
        return updateObjectQuery.execute((AbstractSession) session, (AbstractRecord) arguments);
    }
}
```